# Why cannot I capture the ctrl+C key (KeyBoardInterrupt exception of python) in external terminal of VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I use VS Code to develop python program. And I found it cannot capture the ctrl+C key when using the external terminal, but it worked properly with the integrated terminal.

Here is my python code:

```
import time

print('press enter to start,and press ctrl+C to stop:')
while True:

    input("")
    starttime = time.time()
    print('Started')
    try:
        while True:
            print('Counting:', round(time.time() - starttime, 3), 'seconds',end='\r')
            time.sleep(0.001)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nEnd')
        endtime = time.time()
        print('Total Time:', round(endtime - starttime, 3), 'seconds')
        break
```

and here is my lauch.json file with integrated terminal:

```
{
    "stopOnEntry": false,
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

here is my lauch.json file with external terminal:

```
{
    "stopOnEntry": false,
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

With the external terminal, the code cannot stop when I give it a ctrl+C key. I want to figure out why and how to fix this. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Hi please try ctrl+z instead

It worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Keyboard interrupts to close your program isn't a great way but if you still want to I think it is ctr + alt + m for VS code. To do it the proper way you should use the `keyboard` module:

```
import keyboard

if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
    print('goodbye')
    quit()
```

As mentioned in the comments, OP wants an error to be excepted in which case just use

```
raise Exception('Exiting')
```

In the code:

```
import keyboard

if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
    print('goodbye')
    raise Exception('Exiting')
```

This can caught by:

```
except Exiting:
    print("Key Board Interupt")
```

Comment: But this can't make it stop with an exception

Comment: It is generally considered bad to use an exception, but I'll edit it, hope it helps

Comment: @StarGazerD____